# Pandas Series from two-columned DataFrame produces a Series of NaN's

Tags: python, pandas

```
state_codes = pd.read_csv('name-abbr.csv', header=None)
state_codes.columns = ['State', 'Code']
codes = state_codes['Code']
states = pd.Series(state_codes['State'], index=state_codes['Code'])
```

`name-abbr.csv` is a two-columned CSV file of US state names in the first column and postal codes in the second: "Alabama" and "AL" in the first row, "Alaska" and "AK" in the second, and so forth.

The above code correctly sets the index, but the Series is all `NaN`. If I don't set the index, the state names correctly show. But I want both.

I also tried this line:

```
states = pd.Series(state_codes.iloc[:,0], index=state_codes.iloc[:,1])
```

Same result. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is reason called alignment, it means `pandas` try match index of `state_codes['State'].index` with new index of `state_codes['Code']` and because different get missing values in output, for prevent it is necessary convert Series to numpy array:

```
states = pd.Series(state_codes['State'].to_numpy(), index=state_codes['Code'])
```

Or you can use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
states = state_codes.set_index('Code')['State']
```